# What is the best way for boolean type declaration in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Can anyone please explain which one is a best practice out of the following two type declarations in typescript?

1. `private i : boolean = true;`
2. `private i = true;`

Comment: They are basically the same. One is implicit, the other explicit. Depends on whether you find value in seeing the type explicitly or you think it takes up space. So, either use personal preference or keep to the code style, if any exists.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is subjective.

```
private i: boolean = true;
```

is the most explicit, so it would be unlikely that someone would accidently change the value of `i` to some other type, however, with a simple type this is unlikely so I personally would prefer

`private i = true;`, where the type of boolean is inferred anyway.